# How to animate the div instead of the content

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a hover animation that'll I'd like to animate the div with, but when I added the animation to `#i :hover {}`, it animates the words instead, plus the cursor only turns into a pointer when hovering the words instead of the div.

```css
@keyframes hover {
  0% {bottom: 0px;}
  100% {bottom: 20px;}
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#i {
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(255, 100, 0);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border-radius: 10%;
}

#i :hover {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    animation: hover 0.5s;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="i"><strong>Hover</strong></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I change it so that the entire div would raise up instead?

Comment: Remove the space between the #i and :hover you should have it as `#i:hover` not like `#i :hover`. The space between the `#i` and the `:hover` indicates that you want to animate the children on hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put a space between `#i` and `:hover` this code applies when an element which is a child of `#i` is hovered. You can fix this by removing the space.

```css
#i:hover {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    animation: hover 0.5s;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, spaces matter

```css
@keyframes hover {
  0% {bottom: 0px;}
  100% {bottom: 20px;}
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#i {
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(255, 100, 0);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border-radius: 10%;
}
 
#i:hover {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    animation: hover 0.5s;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="i"><strong>Hover</strong></div>
  </body>
</html>
```